Check_model performance package interpretation plots
I am fairly new to R and statistics and I am building GLMs for frogs occupancy and abundance using a dataset with 57 observations and 13 independent variables. As some variables are correlated the global model has 7 parameters but the best models based on AICc have 2/3 parameters. I used binomial for occupancy while for abundance I tried both negative binomial and zero-inflated negative binomial as there is a relatively high number of zeros (23 observed and 21 predicted).
After building the models I am using the check_model function from the performance package to evaluate these models and I have a few doubts.
Regarding the binomial GLMs:

The posterior predictive check plot shows that the number of predicted counts for 0 and 1 is within the observed data on the y axis but why is there a difference on the x axis? How can the model-predicted data be past 1 on binomial?
About the binned residuals plots all the models with lowest AICc have quite a few points (about 50%) outside the error bounds. Is it always that bad or is it not that bad if the points fall quite close to the error bounds? I have attached the plots for two models: the one with 50% points outside the bounds have AICc around 58 and the other with only one point out have AICc around 62.



Regarding the negative binomial and the zero-inflated negative binomial:

About the misspecified dispersion and zero-inflation plots all models have a similar pattern to the one shared below, where observed and predicted variance are similar until around 5 but then predicted residual variance increase while observed residual variance slightly decrease. I tried to search on the web but I am confused because from what I read residual variance= observed-predicted. So, I would expect a single line whereas the graph show observed residual variance and predicted residual variance.
Concerning the VIF plot for the zero-inflated negative binomial I wonder how the zero-inflated can produce such huge VIF values (>3,000) when in the conditional all values are low or moderate.



